# Creating a scatter plot using two data sets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Beginner here. I'm hoping to create a scatterplot using two datasets that I created using group by:

```
menthlth_perc_bystate <- brfss2013 %>% 
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(percent_instability = sum(menthlth > 15, na.rm = TRUE) / n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(percent_instability))

exercise_perc_bystate <- brfss2013 %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  summarise(perc_exercise = sum(exeroft1 > 30, na.rm = TRUE) / n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(perc_exercise))
```

I want to merge these into one dataset, total_data. Both have 54 obs.

```
total_data <- merge(menthlth_perc_bystate,exercise_perc_bystate,by="state")
```

Presumably the scatter plot would take on one axis the state's percent instability (menthlth_perc_bystate) and on another the states percent exercise (exercise_perc_by_state). I tried this using ggplot but got an error:

`ggplot(total_data, aes(x = total_data$menthlth_perc_bystate, y = total_data$exercise_perc_bystate)) + geom_point()`

The error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (54): x, y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `aes()` function of ggplot you put the bare column names from the data frame you provided for the data argument. So in your example it would be:

```
ggplot(total_data , 
       aes(x = percent_instability,
           y = perc_exercise)) + 
geom_point()
```

Although I'm not sure what `total_ex` is in your example.
Also, using `total_ex$menthlth_perc_bystate` implies you are looking for a column named `menthlth_perc_bystate` in the data frame `total_ex`. That column does not exist, it is the name of a different data frame. Once you have merged the two data frames, the columns in the resulting data frame will  be `state`, `percent_instability`, and `perc_exercise`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Made an edit. Total_ex should be total_data. This works. Thanks!